# Can't use boot from usb after installing ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

I did a full install of Ubuntu 14.04 and am now trying to boot from the ubuntu 14.04 usb that I made but when I switch the boot order in the boot menu to boot from the usb it just goes back to my current install of 14.04 on my hdd and won't let me boot from the usb. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: Did you save the changes after changing the boot-order in bios? Did your Ubuntu live USB is plugged in?

Comment: Yes I saved the boot-order and ensured that my live USB is plugged in.

Comment: @user3598114 It's possible the filesystem on your flash drive is corrupted

Comment: I've tried 2 different flash drives I will try changing the program I use to turn them into bootable usb's

Answer (score 1):

This could be caused by dust in the USB port, a damaged USB port, or filesystem corruption. If a device isn't bootable it will be skipped and the BIOS will choose the next device.

If you see dust in the port try blowing it out with canned air or vacuum it out with an anti-static vac

Confirm that the USB port is working by inserting an inexpensive storage device and checking to see if you can read and write to it.

Try opening a terminal from your installed 14.04

Insert your USB device and determine it's name by issuing the command

```
fdisk -l
```

then

```
umount /dev/sdXy
```

where sdXy is sdb1 or whatever you learned it's name was from the previous step.

then

```
fsck /dev/sdXy
```

where sdXy is sdb1 or whatever you learned it's name was from the first step.